# Is there a cool way to deny robots from whole server, including robots.txt?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to prevent all polite crawler from requesting any resources in my site including /robots.txt. Bad bots are rejected manually.

But 403 for /robots.txt seems to cause most crawlers to continue request.

I'm thinking of using PHP for this work.
And all static contents must be hidden from crawlers.
So I created a PHP script for robots.txt that register IP addresses to the root .htaccess.
All hosts that request /robots.txt should be rejected from all resource.

But I think this will soon slow down my site because the size of the .htaccess will rapidly increase.

http://ochaken.net/.htaccess (public)

Also, I want to allow access to PHP scripts so that it can rejected manually in them.

My plan: A crawler that previously requested robots.txt requests a static content -> 403 by Apache -> PHP script responds.

```
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php


<Files ~ "(\.php$){0}">
    Deny from <a robot's IP>
</Files>
```

But the access to / is also banned by Apache even if it is the same as /index.php.

Is there a right way to do this?

---

edit: these ErrorDocument directives don't work for banned IPs.

Comment: I thought the point of /robots.txt was that you could inform polite crawlers not to crawl anything using: `User-agent: *
Disallow: /`. Without allowing bots to crawl the robots.txt file, there isn't a simple way of blocking/banning them...

Comment: Do you mind me asking **why** exactly you don't want to serve a few bytes long `robots.txt` and prefer to overcomplicate things instead?

Comment: robots.txt not _cool_ enough?

Comment: The website is not for production. I'm developing some software there and the main purpose is trivial technical research.

Comment: This will be a part of a larger access control program. I am looking for a method where the server decides whether a request is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could try blocking access using the User-Agent...

Bots often have the word "Bot" in their user agent:

```
# Very primitive matching for any user agent with "bot" in it
# This will likely block some valid user-agent you don't want to block
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot [NC] 
# This will return a 403 Forbidden status code for any URL requested
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

**EDIT**

So I suppose if you had your /robots.txt redirecting to /robots.php, then in your robots.php could append the two rules above to your .htaccess file, but with a real User Agent.

To prevent duplicates, you could store the user-agent in a database and re-generate that part of your .htaccess every time a new user-agent was seen...

Comment: User-agent filtering is good in performance. But I've found some bots with user agents **exactly** the same as popular browsers. They read robots.txt and remembering user agents for blocking will block all access with the user agents. So I feel the user-agent based solution is not very good. I don't want to think about what name do the client apps have. A method based on _how the client apps act_ may be perfect.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to serve `/robots.txt` at all? It really is the best solution to preventing well behaved bots from crawling the site. Additionally, this kind of blocking won't block badly behaved bots that don't even request `/robots.txt`...

Comment: I'm thinking of using /robots.txt as one of the bot detection method. It will be used with a more complicated method against impolite bots. I want to reject both known bad bots and polite bots  in the same way. After all, I am looking for a method where the server decides whether a request is acceptable. Just wanted to know whether it is possible.